# composing two comparison functions?

Tags: sorting, haskell

I'd like to sort by one property and then by another (if the first property is the same.)

What's the idiomatic way in Haskell of composing two comparison functions, i.e. a function used with `sortBy`?

Given

```
f :: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering
g :: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering
```

composing `f` and `g` would yield:

```
h x y = case v of
          EQ -> g x y
          otherwise -> v
        where v = f x y
```

Comment: Using `Data.Monoid`, you can get: `f x y \`mappend\` g x y`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

vitus points out the very cool instance of `Monoid` for `Ordering`. If you combine it with the instance `instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)` it turns out your composition function is just (get ready):

```
mappend
```

Check it out:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> let f a b = EQ
Prelude Data.Monoid> let g a b = LT
Prelude Data.Monoid> :t f `mappend` g
f `mappend` g :: t -> t1 -> Ordering
Prelude Data.Monoid> (f `mappend` g) undefined undefined 
LT
Prelude Data.Monoid> let f a b = GT
Prelude Data.Monoid> (f `mappend` g) undefined undefined 
GT
```

+1 for powerful and simple abstractions

Comment: I knew that Haskell had to have an elegant solution to this :)  Thank you for explaining it so clearly and concisely.

Comment: This is brilliant. To sort a list of pairs: `sortBy (comparing fst <> comparing snd)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `<>` operator. In this example `bigSort` sorts string by their numerical value, first comparing length and then comparing lexicographically.

```hs
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord (compare, comparing)

bigSort :: [String] -> [String]
bigSort = sortBy $ (comparing length) <> compare
```

Example:

```
bigSort ["31415926535897932384626433832795","1","3","10","3","5"] = 
        ["1","3","3","5","10","31415926535897932384626433832795"]
```

`<>` is an alias of `mappend` from the `Data.Monoid module` (see *jberryman* answer).

The (free) book *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!* explains how it works here in [Chapter 11](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#monoids)

> ```
> instance Monoid Ordering where  
>    mempty = EQ  
>    LT `mappend` _ = LT
>    EQ `mappend` y = y
>    GT `mappend` _ = GT
> ```
>
> The instance is set up like this: when we `mappend` two `Ordering` values, the one on the left is kept, unless the value on the left is `EQ`, in which case the right one is the result. The identity is `EQ`.

Comment: you're missing an explanation for how the Monoid on functions into Monoids works. :)

Comment: You're correct, I thought about it while writing the answer, but I'm not so expert to understand how it works. In this case `compare` and `comparing length` are of type `Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering`, while `Ordering` is an instance of Monoid. For what reason even functions of type `Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering` can be *mappended*?

Comment: for the reason that they are .... `a -> (a -> Ordering)` functions, and `a -> Ordering` functions can be *mappended*! and those can be *mappended*, of course, because `Ordering` values can be *mappended*. :) (nice, isn't it?) so the `instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) where (f <> g) x = f x <> g x` is applied twice, here.

Comment: ... thus giving us `(f <> g) x y = (f x <> g x) y = f x y <> g x y`.