# What does Data.Semigroup ((<>)) do in this Haskell sort code?

Tags: sorting, haskell, compare, semigroup

I know that the program can sort the list by Mfg or by Year(descending). That is defined on line 9 and 10. But what exactly is the code doing? What is (<>)?

```
import Data.Semigroup ((<>))
import Data.List (sort, sortOn)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

data Vehicle = Vehicle { mfg :: String, year  :: Int } deriving (Eq, Show)
mycars =[Vehicle "Saab" 2000, Vehicle "Volvo" 1995]

instance Ord Vehicle where
          compare = flip (comparing year) <> comparing mfg

main = do
          print $ sortOn mfg mycars
          print $ sort mycars
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you're missing indentation before `compare =`. As a result, instead of defining that method in your `Ord` instance, you're creating a broken `Ord` instance and shadowing `compare` at top-level.

Comment: `comparing (Down . year)` might be more suggestive of the intended sorting order than `flip (comparing year)`.

Comment: [cf.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486436/composing-two-comparison-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import Data.Semigroup ((<>))` doesn't do anything useful in your program, and hasn't since GHC 7.10 was released in 2015. Before that, it brought the `<>` operator into scope so that `compare = flip (comparing year) <> comparing mfg` can use it. In GHC 7.10, that operator was added to the Prelude, so it's now always in scope even without importing it.

As for what `<>` does there, you're using it at the type `Vehicle -> Vehicle -> Ordering`. It comes from the `Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b)` instance (twice) and the `Semigroup Ordering` instance. The net effect is that after applying both `Vehicles` to it, it will use the result of the left-hand side comparison on them (`flip (comparing year)`), unless it's `EQ`, in which case it will use the right-hand side comparison (`comparing mfg`) on them instead. If you were to write out by hand exactly what it were doing, it would be this:

```
compare x y = case flip (comparing year) x y of
  LT -> LT
  EQ -> comparing mfg x y
  GT -> GT
```